Losing one's olam haba for embarrassing a non-Jew
The Gemara B”M 59a says one who embarrasses his friend loses his share in the world to come.
My question is, regardless if it’s an issur of embarrassing a non-Jew, if one does though, would he lose his olam haba?

Rambam (De'os 6:8) seems to imply that it's specific to fellow Jews:

כָּךְ אָמְרוּ חֲכָמִים יָכוֹל אַתָּה מוֹכִיחוֹ וּפָנָיו מִשְׁתַּנּוֹת
תַּלְמוּד לוֹמַר וְלֹא תִשָּׂא עָלָיו חֵטְא. מִכָּאן שֶׁאָסוּר לָאָדָם
לְהַכְלִים אֶת יִשְׂרָאֵל וְכָל שֶׁכֵּן בָּרַבִּים. אַף עַל פִּי
שֶׁהַמַּכְלִים אֶת חֲבֵרוֹ אֵינוֹ לוֹקֶה עָלָיו עָוֹן גָּדוֹל הוּא.
כָּךְ אָמְרוּ חֲכָמִים "הַמַּלְבִּין פְּנֵי חֲבֵרוֹ בָּרַבִּים אֵין
לוֹ חֵלֶק לָעוֹלָם הַבָּא".‏
This is what our Sages said: Should you rebuke him to the point that
his face changes [color]? The Torah states: "[You should]... not bear
a sin because of him." From this, [we learn that] it is forbidden for
a person to embarrass a [fellow] Jew. How much more so [is it
forbidden to embarrass him] in public. Even though a person who
embarrasses a colleague is not [liable for] lashes on account of him,
it is a great sin. Our Sages said: "A person who embarrasses a
colleague in public does not have a share in the world to come."

